# Dropping a FTL-rocket onto the Starkiller base

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

As stated in several other answers, the Starkiller base is protected by a flickering shield which can be penetrated by a FTL-object.

But why did they risk the lives of several of the main protagonists by dropping them onto the base in a ship, while it would have been way easier to simply load ships with nukes or similar explosives, accelerate them up to a speed faster than light, and target them onto the weak point?

That would spare them some lives, increase the chance of blowing the base up

> and spare Han

(and shorten the movie significantly).

Comment: Because Rey....

Comment: Because they had a couple of hours, and McGuyvering what you proposed is beyond their resources. They are a shoestring operation, not Mad Science lab

Comment: Because this is "Space Opera". Not a Stanisław Lem novel.

Comment: How would the explosives be set off at the right time? Also, didn't they have to infiltrate the base and plant explosives inside to actually be able to disable the weapon? Even with the shield completely down, proton torpedoes could not damage the weapon enough from the outside. If they had something more powerful than proton torpedoes, they probably would have tried it.

Comment: They wouldn't even need an explosive if they can accelerate any large enough object to light speed. They could find their closest large asteroid, point it at the base, and accelerate it to light speed and the [planet would probably be destroyed](https://what-if.xkcd.com/20/), and that's without even considering all of the energy that Starkiller Base contained at the time of the attack. Time to slap a hyperdrive onto a 50 km asteroid.

Comment: They could even program a droid to fly it.  That way no 'life' was lost.

Comment: @Ellesedil, with an asteroid though I wouldn't think you'd even need to get that fast.. Cool idea though, and pairs well with DVK's logic.

Comment: @Ellesedil - In real physics you can't accelerate an object to light speed, only to some large fraction of it, and since in Star Wars they always talk about "jumps" to light speed I think it's a discontinuous process of moving into hyperspace and instantly traveling FTL once there, rather than continuously increasing speed. And I don't think much has been established about the physics of hyperspace collisions--it's possible they'd release far *less* explosive energy than a collision between a planet and an object moving through ordinary space at say 99.99999% the speed of light relative to it.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: Sure, there's not much we know about the physics of hyperspace. But we do know that [ships in hyperspace can interact with objects in normal space](http://www.flickclip.com/flicks/starwarsanewhope2.html). It's just unclear if a planet is large enough for something into hyperspace to fly into and interact with and what the result of that interaction would be (although I'm willing to bet it'd still be pretty disastrous).

Comment: @Ellesedil - I've recently started watching the Clone Wars series, and the episode ["Destroy Malevolance"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Destroy_Malevolence) (SPOILERS) does feature a large ship whose navicomputer has been tampered with so it jumps to hyperspace while facing a rocky moon--we see a bright flash of impact on the surface but the moon isn't blown up or anything, as it would be in real life in a collision with an object traveling sufficiently close to light speed (since kinetic energy approaches infinity as the speed of any object with mass approaches light speed).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, I figure a common-sense non-canon answer is in order.

Yes, **theoretically**, as the suggestion alluded, the Resistance **maybe could** rig an autonomous vehicle which could/would:

1. get out of hyperspace/lightspeed at just the correct moment

   ... and if someone thinks that this is a trivial thing, please remember that very few ships in TGFFA had automatic pilots.

   If a navicomputer or astromech could do it well, surely there would be far less human pilots, or at least far more autopilots allowing human pilots to chill. None of the canon supports that, and robot pilots are rare and only used on super-routine routes like the one we see in *Paradise Snare* (where Han immediately seized the change and proved to the Fake-Hutts how hotshot of a pilot he was, by taking controls himself and doing a job far superior to the astromech who was supposed to be piloting the cargo ship).
2. time the approach through the flickering shield at just the correct moment

   Probably also far from trivial to construct a program to do this.
3. AND, deliver a weapon good enough to bust the bunker with the oscillator.

   Oh, easy, you say? Just use the nuke? Wrong you are, young Padawan. X-Wings are armed with **proton torpedoes**, which are... you guessed it, nuclear. Yet, Poe and a bunch of OTHER X-Wings pounded the c*(p out of that structure, repeatedly, **to no effect** - until Han's team created an opening in the structure by placing explosives **inside**.
4. Oh... while you, the Resistance leader, are pondering a fancy R&D project to assemble this wonder-combination of superior weaponized hardware and guidance software...

   **you only have a couple of hours to McGuyver all that together**. Because the StarKiller will fry your base in less than a day.

   Oh, and you have a private operation being run on a shoestring. You don't have access to much fancy or expensive stuff - your top of the line military hardware is under 30 X-Wings.

So, If I'm such a  Resistance leader, I go with what works - namely, Yet Another Insane Scheme from Han Solo. Because at least, that one is off the shelf and available to me on a moment's notice, harebrained and dangerous though it is.

Comment: "time the approach through the flickering shield at just the correct moment"  You literally have to construct a program to do this. You cannot actually expect a human to time this right, especially in conjunction with your point 1. I agree with your assessment that the hyperspace-nuke plan is full of huge holes, but what Han does in the movie doesn't make any sense either.

Comment: Traveling at the speed of light, it will take you about 1/23rd of a second to pass through an Earth-sized planet entirely; you'd have to have the timing down to nanoseconds to stop just short of the surface while traveling faster than the speed of light and evading the refresh rate.

Comment: He's not human. He's Han Solo. He has Solo luck

Answer (score 1):

Because Leia wanted (Han) to try and save their son.

Comment: Leia isn't an absolute dictator though, and I doubt the other Resistance leaders would allow her to risk the lives of billions for the sake of having a chance of saving her son.

Comment: From what I remember, we didn't see much, if anything, of the other resistance leaders so this is speculation.